# Converting a piece of code into a function, and how to take the function into use. VBA VBA VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, function

How to make the following code into a function so I can just call it by entering something like `Function functionname(Cell1, Cell2)`?

I want to specify that I am a super scrub, and would really like it if you could show me exactly how it is done with call values and everything. For intance if I need to write function `functionname(Cell1.value, Cell2.value)` in order for it to work?
Overall I seek knowledge on how to make this code into a function and how to use that function later on in the code?
Remember I'm a complete scrub at VBA so be specific please. Preferably show working examples.

```
  Arr = Split(Range("G3").Value, ".")
    If Arr(3) = 254 Then
        Arr(3) = 1
        If Arr(2) < 254 Then
            Arr(2) = Arr(2) + 1
        Else
            Arr(2) = 1
            If Arr(1) < 254 Then
                Arr(1) = Arr(1) + 1
            Else
                Arr(1) = 1
                If Arr(0) < 254 Then
                    Arr(0) = Arr(0) + 1
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error! No more IP's available"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Arr(3) = Arr(3) + 1
    End If

    Range("G2").Value = Join(Arr, ".")


End Sub
```

Comment: Ok... So you ask questions on how to change my code I gave you yesterday, but accepted someone elses answer? ||| Do you want it as a UDF och a real VBA code that you activate as a macro? Or perhaps a button on the sheet that you click on?

Comment: Yea sorry I'm still new to the forums so didn't know if it was good if I posted further questions in my same question. And I didn't know how to credit the code to you either..  :S Anyway what I'm currently working with is having the code as a macro, but the macro makes this code for several cells where the IP needs to change, and not just one. So instead of writing such a long piece of code for each cell, I wanted to narrow it down to one function, where I could just give the 2 inputs wich would be the cell in row3 and the cell in row2.

Comment: You use the accept button on the answer you think suits you best, then the upvote can be used on those who gave you a good answer but not the one you like, and downvote the ones that make a poor answer. I bet you can find out how that works if you visit the help pages of the site. What is the row3 and row2? You give very little information

Comment: To clarify: In the current example it is G2 and G3. I have several others in the same rows that need the same conversion like Z2 and Z3, AB2 and AB3 and so on. And I wish to make it so that I can just call the function of your if/else statements in the code, instead of having to write that entire piece of code again and again filling out the module with thousand of lines of code when it could be much more simple.

Comment: And they are all IPs that need the same function with adding one to the value?

Comment: Yes indeed they are, It's just different scopes thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. All you need to do is change the range in the `sub newloc()`.

```
Sub newloc()

   Range("G2").Value = PlusOne(Range("G2").Value)
   Range("Z2").Value = PlusOne(Range("Z2").Value)
   Range("AB2").Value = PlusOne(Range("AB2").Value)



End Sub



Function PlusOne(IP)
    Arr = Split(IP, ".")
    if(instr(Arr(3), "/")<>0) then
        prefix = mid(Arr(3), instr(Arr(3), "/"))
        Arr(3) = left(Arr(3), instr(Arr(3), "/")-1)
    end if
    If Arr(3) = 254 Then
        Arr(3) = 1
        If Arr(2) < 254 Then
            Arr(2) = Arr(2) + 1
        Else
            Arr(2) = 1
            If Arr(1) < 254 Then
                Arr(1) = Arr(1) + 1
            Else
                Arr(1) = 1
                If Arr(0) < 254 Then
                    Arr(0) = Arr(0) + 1
                Else
                    MsgBox "Error! No more IP's available"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Arr(3) = Arr(3) + 1
    End If

    if prefix <>"" then Arr(3) = Arr(3) & prefix
    PlusOne = Join(Arr, ".")
End Function
```

EDIT: added the Z and AB column to make the code more clear on how to use it.

Comment: You're always the champ man thx a bunch Already accepted your answer, and accepted your old one too

Comment: @Murgo Do you expect that you will run out of IPs at any time? I could change the code to give you a better error message in case you do run out of IP's

Comment: Oh wait after tumbling around with it it still doesent work for some reason. I can't seem to find the error?, Even if I make a new module and just copy paste your code it still comes with a mismatch type error??

Comment: PS. no we don't expect that to happen anytime soon :P I changed the code where I had to, and there are passages where I only need the 3rd or even the 2nd octet to change, which I figured out how to no problems. We won't run out anytime soon :D but thx for asking

Comment: heh I think you misunderstood I have trouble understanding why the code you wrote me has a runtime error even before I have made any changes to it? :D

Comment: Oh.. Sorry didn't see that... Where do you get the error and on what value is the code running?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but work got busy, anyway if I copy paste your code into a clean module and then try to run the macro, it says runtime error 12 type mismatch, and its on one of the last lines the: Arr(3) = Arr(3) + 1

Comment: And what value is in the cell that you are running it on? It seems you may have a three set IP since it stops at the arr(3) line.

Comment: values like this 172.16.36.0/24

Comment: It is.. 0/24 is read as a string, and you can't add a number to a string. How should the code handle the 0/24? What does it mean?

Comment: its called a prefix and its going to be the same for all the IP's in the respective columns

Comment: So in case there is a / in the IP nothing should be done to it? Or how should +1 be done? 0/24 -> 1/25?

Comment: 172.17.2.0/24 --> 172.17.2.1/24

Comment: Ok... And that is only on the last part of the IP? You don't have an IP that is 127.244.2/26.1?

Comment: nop : ) the prefix (/24) ends the IP. Writing something after that wont ever happen.

Comment: As far as I can gather, the /24 should just be considered a static string that stays the same through the entire progression of the IP addresses.

Comment: Ok.. I updated the code, it's untested so try it on dummy values. But it should split the prefix from the code and then add it at the last moment.

Comment: awesome ! I'm looking forward to see it : D

Answer (score 0):

Just define your code as a function. Check this webpage to get more information...
Make sure you create the module in the same worksheet where you want to use your function.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

As an example I will send you this little function that I just created to ilustrate you how to do it...

```
Function funct_sum(x As Integer, y As Integer)

    funct_sum = x + y

End Function
```

This function will now be available in your excel worksheet.